# Hide / show buttons with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this function which hides some buttons and create another button, when I click on the button created it should make again visible those who were hidden before , but it doesn't really work.

```
function hideButtons(){
    var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
        if(buttons[i].type=="button"){
        buttons[i].style.display="none";}

    }

    var back=document.createElement("input");
    back.setAttribute("type", "button");
    back.setAttribute("value","BACK");
    back.setAttribute("id","btnBack");
    back.onclick=showButtons();
    document.body.appendChild(back);


}


function showButtons(){
    var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("input");


    for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++) {
        buttons[i].style.display="initial";

    }
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle or similar to run your code? I might need some html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not call the listener function when you attach the event listener:

```
function hideButtons () {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");

  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.display = "none";
    if (buttons[i].getAttribute("id") === "btnBack") {
      // remove the id from the current "back" button
      buttons[i].removeAttribute("id");
    }
  }

  var back = document.createElement("input");
  back.setAttribute("type", "button");
  back.setAttribute("value","BACK");
  back.setAttribute("id","btnBack");
  back.onclick = showButtons; // important!
  document.body.appendChild(back);
}


function showButtons () {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.display = "initial";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like PeterMader said the problem is that you're calling the `showButtons()` function in the event listener. You want to call a reference to the function like Peter suggested, or another way is to wrap `showButtons()` in a function.

```js
function hideButtons() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].type == "button") {
      buttons[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  var back = document.createElement("input");
  back.setAttribute("type", "button");
  back.setAttribute("value", "BACK");
  back.setAttribute("id", "btnBack");
  back.onclick = function() {
    showButtons();
  }
  document.body.appendChild(back);
}

function showButtons() {
  var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.display = "initial";
  }
}

hideButtons();
```

```html
<input type="button">
<input type="button">
<input type="button">
<input>
```